# C Threadsafe Priority Queue O(log n) push, O(1) pop

Tags: c, multithreading, queue, priority-queue

I wrote this for an A* implementation:

(pqueue.c)

```
#include "pqueue.h"
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct pqueue* new_pqueue(size_t capacity, int mt) {
    struct pqueue* pqueue = malloc(sizeof(struct pqueue));
    pqueue->capacity = capacity;
    pqueue->data = malloc((capacity == 0 ? 1 : capacity) * sizeof(struct __pqueue_entry));
    pqueue->rc = capacity == 0 ? 1 : 0;
    pqueue->start = 0;
    pqueue->end = 0;
    pqueue->size = 0;
    pqueue->mt = mt;
    if (mt) {
        if (pthread_mutex_init(&pqueue->data_mutex, NULL)) {
            free(pqueue->data);
            pqueue->data = NULL;
            free(pqueue);
            return NULL;
        }
        if (pthread_mutex_init(&pqueue->out_mutex, NULL)) {
            free(pqueue->data);
            pqueue->data = NULL;
            free(pqueue);
            pthread_mutex_destroy(&pqueue->data_mutex);
            return NULL;
        }
        if (pthread_mutex_init(&pqueue->in_mutex, NULL)) {
            free(pqueue->data);
            pqueue->data = NULL;
            free(pqueue);
            pthread_mutex_destroy(&pqueue->data_mutex);
            pthread_mutex_destroy(&pqueue->out_mutex);
            return NULL;
        }
        if (pthread_cond_init(&pqueue->out_cond, NULL)) {
            free(pqueue->data);
            pqueue->data = NULL;
            free(pqueue);
            pthread_mutex_destroy(&pqueue->data_mutex);
            pthread_mutex_destroy(&pqueue->out_mutex);
            pthread_mutex_destroy(&pqueue->in_mutex);
            return NULL;
        }
        if (pthread_cond_init(&pqueue->in_cond, NULL)) {
            free(pqueue->data);
            pqueue->data = NULL;
            free(pqueue);
            pthread_mutex_destroy(&pqueue->data_mutex);
            pthread_mutex_destroy(&pqueue->out_mutex);
            pthread_mutex_destroy(&pqueue->in_mutex);
            pthread_cond_destroy(&pqueue->out_cond);
            return NULL;
        }
    }
    return pqueue;
}

int del_pqueue(struct pqueue* pqueue) {
    if (pqueue == NULL || pqueue->data == NULL) return -1;
    if (pqueue->mt) {
        if (pthread_mutex_destroy(&pqueue->data_mutex)) return -1;
        if (pthread_mutex_destroy(&pqueue->out_mutex)) return -1;
        if (pthread_cond_destroy(&pqueue->out_cond)) return -1;
        if (pthread_mutex_destroy(&pqueue->in_mutex)) return -1;
        if (pthread_cond_destroy(&pqueue->in_cond)) return -1;
    }
    free(pqueue->data);
    pqueue->data = NULL;
    free(pqueue);
    return 0;
}

int add_pqueue(struct pqueue* pqueue, void* data, float priority) {
    if (pqueue->mt) pthread_mutex_lock(&pqueue->data_mutex);
    if (pqueue->size == pqueue->rc && pqueue->capacity == 0) {
        size_t orc = pqueue->rc;
        pqueue->rc += 1024 / sizeof(struct __pqueue_entry);
        struct __pqueue_entry* ndata = malloc(pqueue->rc * sizeof(struct __pqueue_entry));
        if (pqueue->start < pqueue->end) {
            memcpy(ndata, pqueue->data + pqueue->start, (pqueue->end - pqueue->start) * sizeof(struct __pqueue_entry));
        } else {
            memcpy(ndata, pqueue->data + pqueue->start, (orc - pqueue->start) * sizeof(struct __pqueue_entry));
            memcpy(ndata + (orc - pqueue->start), pqueue->data + pqueue->end, (pqueue->start - pqueue->end) * sizeof(struct __pqueue_entry));
        }
        free(pqueue->data);
        pqueue->data = ndata;
    } else if (pqueue->capacity == 0) {
    } else {
        if (!pqueue->mt) return 1;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&pqueue->data_mutex);
        pthread_mutex_lock(&pqueue->in_mutex);
        while (pqueue->size == pqueue->capacity) {
            pthread_cond_wait(&pqueue->in_cond, &pqueue->in_mutex);
        }
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&pqueue->in_mutex);
        pthread_mutex_lock(&pqueue->data_mutex);
    }
    struct __pqueue_entry pd;
    pd.ptr = data;
    pd.prio = priority;
    float i = (float) pqueue->size / 2.;
    float ts = (float) pqueue->size / 2.;
    size_t rp = pqueue->capacity > 0 ? pqueue->capacity : pqueue->rc;
    int tc = 0;
    int fri = 0;
    while (ts > 0.) {
        int ri = (int) i + pqueue->start;
        if (ri >= rp) ri -= rp;
        if (pqueue->data[ri].prio > pd.prio) i -= ts;
        else i += ts;
        if (i < 0.) i = 0.;
        if (i > pqueue->size) {
            i = pqueue->size - 1;
        }
        if ((ri == pqueue->end || pqueue->data[ri].prio > pd.prio) && (ri == pqueue->start || pqueue->data[ri - 1].prio < pd.prio)) {
            fri = ri;
            break;
        }
        ts /= 2.;
        tc++;
    }
    if (fri <= pqueue->end) {
        if (pqueue->end > pqueue->start) {
            memmove(pqueue->data + fri + 1, pqueue->data + fri, (pqueue->end - fri) * sizeof(struct __pqueue_entry));
        } else if (fri > pqueue->start) {
            memmove(pqueue->data + 1, pqueue->data, pqueue->end * sizeof(struct __pqueue_entry));
            memcpy(pqueue->data, pqueue->data + rp - 1, sizeof(struct __pqueue_entry));
            memmove(pqueue->data + fri + 1, pqueue->data + fri, (rp - (pqueue->start) - fri) * sizeof(struct __pqueue_entry));
        } else {
            memmove(pqueue->data + fri + 1, pqueue->data + fri, (pqueue->end - fri) * sizeof(struct __pqueue_entry));
        }
    }
    pqueue->end++;
    memcpy(pqueue->data + fri, &pd, sizeof(struct __pqueue_entry));
    if (pqueue->end >= rp) {
        if (pqueue->end - rp == pqueue->start) {
            size_t orc = pqueue->rc;
            pqueue->rc += 1024 / sizeof(struct __pqueue_entry);
            struct __pqueue_entry* ndata = malloc(pqueue->rc * sizeof(struct __pqueue_entry));
            if (pqueue->start < pqueue->end) {
                memcpy(ndata, pqueue->data + pqueue->start, (pqueue->end - pqueue->start) * sizeof(struct __pqueue_entry));
            } else {
                memcpy(ndata, pqueue->data + pqueue->start, (orc - pqueue->start) * sizeof(struct __pqueue_entry));
                memcpy(ndata + (orc - pqueue->start), pqueue->data + pqueue->end, (pqueue->start - pqueue->end) * sizeof(struct __pqueue_entry));
            }
            free(pqueue->data);
            pqueue->data = ndata;
        } else pqueue->end -= rp;
    }
    pqueue->size++;
    if (pqueue->mt) {
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&pqueue->data_mutex);
        pthread_cond_signal(&pqueue->out_cond);
    }
    return 0;
}

void* pop_pqueue(struct pqueue* pqueue) {
    if (pqueue->mt) {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&pqueue->out_mutex);
        while (pqueue->size == 0) {
            pthread_cond_wait(&pqueue->out_cond, &pqueue->out_mutex);
        }
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&pqueue->out_mutex);
        pthread_mutex_lock(&pqueue->data_mutex);
    } else if (pqueue->size == 0) {
        return NULL;
    }
    struct __pqueue_entry data = pqueue->data[pqueue->start++];
    size_t rp = pqueue->capacity > 0 ? pqueue->capacity : pqueue->rc;
    if (pqueue->start >= rp) {
        pqueue->start -= rp;
    }
    pqueue->size--;
    if (pqueue->mt) {
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&pqueue->data_mutex);
        pthread_cond_signal(&pqueue->in_cond);
    }
    return data.ptr;
}

void* timedpop_pqueue(struct pqueue* pqueue, struct timespec* abstime) {
    if (pqueue->mt) {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&pqueue->out_mutex);
        while (pqueue->size == 0) {
            int x = pthread_cond_timedwait(&pqueue->out_cond, &pqueue->out_mutex, abstime);
            if (x) {
                pthread_mutex_unlock(&pqueue->out_mutex);
                errno = x;
                return NULL;
            }
        }
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&pqueue->out_mutex);
        pthread_mutex_lock(&pqueue->data_mutex);
    } else if (pqueue->size == 0) {
        return NULL;
    }
    struct __pqueue_entry data = pqueue->data[pqueue->start++];
    size_t rp = pqueue->capacity > 0 ? pqueue->capacity : pqueue->rc;
    if (pqueue->start >= rp) {
        pqueue->start -= rp;
    }
    pqueue->size--;
    if (pqueue->mt) {
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&pqueue->data_mutex);
        pthread_cond_signal(&pqueue->in_cond);
    }
    return data.ptr;
}
```

(pqueue.h)

```
#ifndef pqueue_H_
#define pqueue_H_

#include <pthread.h>

struct __pqueue_entry {
        float prio;
        void* ptr;
};

struct pqueue {
        size_t size;
        size_t capacity;
        size_t start;
        size_t end;
        size_t rc;
        struct __pqueue_entry* data;
        pthread_mutex_t data_mutex;
        pthread_mutex_t in_mutex;
        pthread_cond_t in_cond;
        pthread_mutex_t out_mutex;
        pthread_cond_t out_cond;
        int mt;
};

struct pqueue* new_pqueue(size_t capacity, int mt); // mt = multithreaded

int del_pqueue(struct pqueue* pqueue);

int add_pqueue(struct pqueue* pqueue, void* data, float priority);

void* pop_pqueue(struct pqueue* pqueue);

void* timedpop_pqueue(struct pqueue* pqueue, struct timespec* abstime);

#endif /* pqueue_H_ */
```

Test code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "pqueue.h"

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    char* s[] = { "s1", "s2", "s3", "s4", "s5", "s6", "s7", "s8" };
    struct pqueue* queue = new_pqueue(0, 0);
    add_pqueue(queue, s[6], 7.);
    add_pqueue(queue, s[1], 2.);
    add_pqueue(queue, s[3], 4.);
    add_pqueue(queue, s[0], 1.);
    add_pqueue(queue, s[4], 5.);
    add_pqueue(queue, s[7], 8.);
    add_pqueue(queue, s[5], 6.);
    add_pqueue(queue, s[2], 3.);
    for (int x = 0; x < 8; x++) {
        printf("%s\n", (char*) pop_pqueue(queue));
    }
    del_pqueue(queue);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Doesn't work if mt == 0

If looks like the code is supposed to support both multithreaded and non-multithreaded cases.  However, in `add_pqueue()`, there is this code:

> ```
> } else {
>     if (!pqueue->mt) return 1;
> ```

The effect of this is to always abort if multithreading is off.  I think you meant to do this instead:

```
} else if (pqueue->mt) {
```

#### Mutexes and conditions not used properly

Consider this code in `pop_queue()`:

> ```
> if (pqueue->mt) {
>     pthread_mutex_lock(&pqueue->out_mutex);
>     while (pqueue->size == 0) {
>         pthread_cond_wait(&pqueue->out_cond, &pqueue->out_mutex);
>     }
>     pthread_mutex_unlock(&pqueue->out_mutex);
>     pthread_mutex_lock(&pqueue->data_mutex);
> ```

The goal of `out_mutex` and `out_cond` is to wait for the queue to be non-empty before proceeding to lock `data_mutex` and actually popping from the queue.  However, consider the case where `size == 1` initially.  What could happen is:

1. Two threads call `pop_queue()`.
2. Each thread gets past the size check and arrives at the line which is about to lock `data_mutex`.
3. Thread 0 locks `data_mutex`, pops an element from the queue, and unlocks `data_mutex`.  This empties the queue, setting `size` to 0.
4. Thread 1 locks `data_mutex`, and then tries to pop from an empty queue, resulting in an error.

The same problem also happens in `add_queue()` but with the size full check.

What I suggest is:

1. Only use one mutex, `data_mutex`.
2. If you get past the size check while holding `data_mutex`, then just proceed.

The code from above becomes:

```
if (pqueue->mt) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&pqueue->data_mutex);
    while (pqueue->size == 0) {
        pthread_cond_wait(&pqueue->out_cond, &pqueue->data_mutex);
    }
```

#### Add isn't \$O(\log n)\$

I took a closer look at your add function and it appears to do a binary search to find an insertion point followed by using one or more calls to `memmove()` to make an open slot in the queue to insert the new element.  The memory moving takes \$O(n)\$ time.  If you used a heap data structure, you could achieve \$O(\log n)\$.

Also, as a member of the *Floating Point Police™*, I disapprove of using floating point to do the binary search.  This can be done using only integer arithmetic.

Comment: The line checking `pqueue->mt` is intended to return if the capacity is set to a non-zero(so non-expandable), and the queue is full. Notice the condition after it to wait until full if it is mt. Also, isn't the flooring of the dividing going to be an issue for the binary search? That's why I used floats. Thank you for the review.

Comment: @JavaProphet Maybe you should explain what your code is supposed to do.  What does capacity == 0 vs capacity > 0 mean?  What does `mt` mean?  What does `rc` mean?  It wasn't clear to me.  Also, where did you learn about binary search with floats instead of ints?  I've never seen binary search done with floats.

Comment: I was concerned about errors with it flooring values on divide (5 / 2 = 2, etc), so I just used floats, didn't learn it anywhere. Your right, I still need to name my variables better!

Comment: @JavaProphet Also, why should `add_queue()` return an error if the capacity is non-zero, and `mt` is false?

Comment: `mt` means multithreaded (if true, it can wait for space), and if `capacity` is 0, it will expand the queue as needed. So if the capacity is limited, the queue is full, and we cannot wait for space, we have to return.

Comment: @JavaProphet Ok I see what you are trying to do, but at the point where you return, you haven't checked if the queue is full yet.

Comment: Oh, good point.

Answer (score 2):

Just a small review:

```
// Did code use the right type here? -----------------------------v
 pqueue->data = malloc((capacity == 0 ? 1 : capacity) * sizeof(struct __pqueue_entry));
```

How does one check that?
Reviewer needs to search `pqueue.h`, find the field `data` as below and then say - OK no problem.

```
struct __pqueue_entry* data;
```

---

Instead, suppose the code used the size of the de-referenced variable:

```
 pqueue->data = malloc(sizeof *(pqueue->data) * (capacity == 0 ? 1 : capacity));
```

Oh happy day! - no problem here - no time wasted - no *need* to code the type.

---

Consider this 2nd style.  Easier to code, less chance of coding error, easier to review and maintain.

Answer (score 2):

Some additions to what has already been mentioned:

1. In `new_pqueue` you invoke undefined behaviour:

   > ```
   > if (pthread_mutex_init(&pqueue->out_mutex, NULL)) {
   >     free(pqueue->data);
   >     pqueue->data = NULL;
   >     free(pqueue);
   >     pthread_mutex_destroy(&pqueue->data_mutex);
   >     return NULL;
   > }
   > ```

   You access `pqueue` after calling `free`. Generally you should cleanup resources in the reverse order and since the mutex been created last it should be destroyed first.
2. You don't check the return value of `malloc`. It would be cleaner to release the allocated memory and simply return `NULL` and leave the caller to deal with it.
3. The header file is basically the public interface to your implementation. Internal details like `struct __pqueue_entry` have no business of being there.
4. In the end most variables or field are `int` or `float` or whatever other primitive type is available - what distinguishes them is the semantics the programmer gives them. In languages like C the only real way to convey that semantics to the reader is the name you give fields and variables. This makes the code easier to read and maintain and understandable by others.
   Short-cut names like `rc` or `mt` are fairly useless since they simply fail to convey the purpose properly.
   Using descriptive names is more important than saving a few keystrokes.
5. This code:

   > ```
   > size_t orc = pqueue->rc;
   > pqueue->rc += 1024 / sizeof(struct __pqueue_entry);
   > struct __pqueue_entry* ndata = malloc(pqueue->rc * sizeof(struct __pqueue_entry));
   > if (pqueue->start < pqueue->end) {
   >     memcpy(ndata, pqueue->data + pqueue->start, (pqueue->end - pqueue->start) * sizeof(struct __pqueue_entry));
   > } else {
   >     memcpy(ndata, pqueue->data + pqueue->start, (orc - pqueue->start) * sizeof(struct __pqueue_entry));
   >     memcpy(ndata + (orc - pqueue->start), pqueue->data + pqueue->end, (pqueue->start - pqueue->end) * sizeof(struct __pqueue_entry));
   > }
   > free(pqueue->data);
   > pqueue->data = ndata;
   > ```

   which resizes the queue is duplicated and should be extracted into its own method.